# One Bot App to support many Facebook pages

Tags: botframework

I'm using the Microsoft Bot Framework with one bot configured with Facebook Channel. In the past, I was able to subscribe as many pages as I wanted in the same bot app but starting from Yesterday, any change I make on Facebook subscription replaces the previous page. 
Is there a way to support many Facebook pages without having to create a bot app for each one?

Comment: `In the past, I was able to subscribe as many pages as I wanted` : are you sure about that? Never experienced this possibility..

Comment: Yes. Even thought the UI did not indicate it, you could simply remove the previous page id, access token , save and both the previous and new would work.This has changed recently. Any change on the Facebook channel subscription will replace the one just before. All the other pages subscribed in the past are still working for now.

Comment: @Sara There was a bug that allowed the functionality you mention (saving a new page id was not removing the old page id, and they both would function).  This has been fixed.  You now need multiple bot registrations in order to handle multiple facebook pages.

Comment: Will this be a future feature soon? Since my Facebook App supports multiple pages, I expect the Microsoft Bot app to do the same

Comment: @EricDahlvang Do you have a workaround for that? It basically requires a new Facebook app for each registrations - which means you need to authorize an app for each page?